# Write a method that will swap the contents of textBox1 and textBox2 c#

Tags: swap

I have this code, but I want to make it more straightforward.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        textBox1.Text = y.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = x.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Have you try just to do that directly? Both properties are strings,   textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;

Comment: Yes, textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text; only puts the text from textBox2 in textBox1. But, I need them to both switch to the content of each other.

Comment: Then you should try adding an aux variable:   aux = text1   text1 = text2  text2 = aux

Comment: Okay. I don't think I'm supposed to use an aux variable because we have not learned about that in my course yet. But thank you for helping me.